# Why does Org mode LaTeX export ignore optional short caption?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm exporting an org mode file to pdf via LaTeX. The file contains images with captions

```
#+CAPTION[Short caption]: Full caption that is way too long to fit into the list of figures
#+NAME: fig:foo
file:img/foo.pdf
```

The short caption only makes it into the exported LaTeX file in about a third of the cases. The list-of-figures is cluttered by entries going on over multiple lines.

If all short captions would be missing, I'd assume a configuration error. But they either appear or not with no discernible pattern. Why is this happening?

Comment: Not that I recall: a short test with essentially what you show above works fine for me. IIUC, sometimes you get `\caption[short]{long}` and sometimes you get `\caption{long}` in the TeX file?

Comment: yes, exactly. The error is somewhere in the org->tex exporter. xetex renders what is contained in the tex-file correctly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that: the short caption consistently gets exported to the `.tex` file. Do you have a minimal example where it breaks?